# Mith Load Capacity

Tags: performance, mirth

We have Mirth 3.6.2 (working to upgrade to 4.x) running on RHEL. What are the KPIs to focus on to see if you have maxed out your server? What are the resources you can add before it makes sense to add a new server? From what I've read, it sounds like you can add RAM and increase the HEAP size, but to what extent?